# Storybook's render function doesn't work. What am I doing wrong?

Tags: reactjs, render, storybook

everyone!!

My problem is related to a storybook render of an accordion group based on a list of single accordions. On a first step, I did an Accordion.stories.tsx file, and then I started to do an AccordionGroup.stories.tsx, that used a single accordion component and its story. I tried to use render structure, but it's underlined in red. Maybe it's a type of problem or something I don't understand.

An Error message in storybook: cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'args').

**`Accordion.stories.tsx`**

```
import { Meta, StoryObj } from "@storybook/react";
import { Accordion } from "ui-kit";

const meta = {
  title: "Accordion",
  component: Accordion,
  tags: ["autodocs"],
} satisfies Meta<typeof Accordion>;

export default meta;
type Story = StoryObj<typeof meta>;

/* First card */
export const First: Story = {
  args: {
    title: "Card one",
    children: "Lorem 1 ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Ex alias laborum voluptate amet neque eos, sed iure debitis voluptatem molestias voluptatibus cumque in qui placeat sequi possimus maiores! Sed, numquam!",
  },
};

/* Second card */
export const Second: Story = {
  args: {
    title: "Card two",
    children: "Lorem 2 ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Ex alias laborum voluptate amet neque eos, sed iure debitis voluptatem molestias voluptatibus cumque in qui placeat sequi possimus maiores! Sed, numquam!",
  },
};

/* Third card */
export const Third: Story = {
  args: {
    title: "Card three",
    children: "Lorem 3 ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Ex alias laborum voluptate amet neque eos, sed iure debitis voluptatem molestias voluptatibus cumque in qui placeat sequi possimus maiores! Sed, numquam!",
  },
};
```

**`AccordionGroup.stories.tsx`**

```
import { Meta, StoryObj } from "@storybook/react";
import { Accordion, AccordionGroup } from "ui-kit";
import * as AccordionStories from "./Accordion.stories";

const meta = {
  title: "AccordionGroup",
  component: AccordionGroup,
  tags: ["autodocs"],
} satisfies Meta<typeof AccordionGroup>;

export default meta;
type Story = StoryObj<typeof AccordionGroup>;

/* Card Group */
export const CardGroup: Story = {
  args: {
    title: "Group Card",
  },
  render: (args) => {
    return <AccordionGroup {...args}>
      <Accordion {...AccordionStories.First.args} />
      <Accordion {...AccordionStories.Second.args} />
      <Accordion {...AccordionStories.Third.args} />
    </AccordionGroup>;
  }
};
```

Before I add "return" to a render part here:

```
render: (args) => {
    return <AccordionGroup {...args}>
      <Accordion {...AccordionStories.First.args} />
      <Accordion {...AccordionStories.Second.args} />
      <Accordion {...AccordionStories.Third.args} />
    </AccordionGroup>;
  }
```

An error message related to a types problems. Such as:

```
Type '(args: IAccordionGroupProps) => void' is not assignable to type 'ArgsStoryFn<ReactRenderer, IAccordionGroupProps>'.
  Type 'void' is not assignable to type 'StoryFnReactReturnType'.ts(2322)
index.d.ts(1163, 5): The expected type comes from property 'render' which is declared here on type 'StoryAnnotations<ReactRenderer, IAccordionGroupProps>'
(property) render?: ArgsStoryFn<ReactRenderer, IAccordionGroupProps> | undefined
Define a custom render function for the story(ies). If not passed, a default render function by the renderer will be used.
```

p.s. types of Accordion component:

```
export interface IAccordionProps {
  className?: string;
  title?: string;
  isActive?: boolean;
  children?: React.ReactNode;
}
```

types of Accordion Group component:

```
export interface IAccordionGroupProps {
  title?: string;
  children?: ReactNode;
}
```

Maybe it's a wrong way to do it like that at all? As I see it should have one global story for a single accordion and a group of it. In my example, I did it separately. It has to be connected to each other, right?

How to fix it? Or what should I do to create a correct story of Accordion Group with Accordions? For example like this one:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H369k.png)

Answer (score 0):

It seems like your render function is not formatted properly and returning `void`

Could you try to replace

```
render: (args) => {
    return <AccordionGroup {...args}>
      <Accordion {...AccordionStories.First.args} />
      <Accordion {...AccordionStories.Second.args} />
      <Accordion {...AccordionStories.Third.args} />
    </AccordionGroup>;
  }
```

with

```
render: (args) => (
  <AccordionGroup {...args}>
      <Accordion {...AccordionStories.First.args} />
      <Accordion {...AccordionStories.Second.args} />
      <Accordion {...AccordionStories.Third.args} />
    </AccordionGroup>
)
```